# In WPF, in MenuItem's template, if set Background in IsHighlighted trigger, then Background IsPressed trigger is invalid

Tags: wpf, templates, triggers, styles, menuitem

I want the MenuItem have the IsMouseOver and IsPressed status with different Background, but after try some times, still be failed.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing... Are you not able to apply effects?.. Please share details.. codes that you tried if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubmarineX.. Menu consists of lots of sub controls.. if you want to set background colors of Menuitems.. then you need to define styles for Out menu items as well as inner menu items...

```
 <Grid>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <!-- Outermenu items-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

            <!-- Submenu items -->
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border Name="Border">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="Icon" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon" />
                        <Border Name="Check" Width="13" Height="13" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="6,0,6,0" Background="#0f3c5a"
                                BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#5082a4">
                            <Path Name="CheckMark" Width="7" Height="7" Visibility="Hidden" SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                                  Stroke="#5082a4" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" 
                                   Margin="5,2,0,2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>

        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="_Cut">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/cut.ico" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/copy.ico" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                <MenuItem Header="_Y"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_X"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Paste">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/paste.ico" Height="16" Width="16" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_View" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Window" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

If you want to style menu header as well then you need to define your styles for MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey as well.... Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank u, just like the effect. Um, I think I should take some time to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this style

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Menu -L Menuitem1 -L MenuItem2, if leftmousedown on the Menuitem2, the background isn't changed.